# geopandas rasterize shpefile

Tags: geopandas, rasterizing, rasterio

I am looking for the very simplest way to rasterise a shpfile in geopandas - the equivalent to arcpy PolygonToRaster_conversion() which does things in one line.

I have found some relatively involved methods eg 
https://snorfalorpagus.net/blog/2014/11/09/masking-rasterio-layers-with-vector-features/

is it this complicated? or is there a one line option like arcpy's PolygonToRaster_conversion()

I'm looking for the simplest starting point to get the idea

I've been exploring rasterio to do this, but perhaps there are other ways

I'm only just starting to  use Geopandas and would appreciate any pointers

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to rasterize a set of polygons with unique values in one step?  If so, you want to [rasterize](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/features.html) using that unique value for each polygon, but beware that the last polygon rasterized to a given pixel will "claim" it (i.e., multiple polygons may touch a pixel, but the last one in your list of features will be the value rasterized there).

Or do you want to rasterize each polygon independently (or all polygons at the same time, as if they were a single polygon), so that you can extract out statistics from the raster?  [Mask](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/masking-by-shapefile.html) may work for this, in a loop over each feature.

The closest you are likely to get to a one-line operation is using `rasterio's` [rio mask](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli.html#mask) or [rio rasterize](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli.html#rasterize) operation.  The reason that the example you link to is more involved is that you need to do a few extra things to extract a subset of your original raster.  There are now a few extra methods in rasterio that make that a bit easier ([docs](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.mask.html)).

From geopandas, your geometry is in a `GeoSeries`.  I haven't tested this directly, but you may need to call the `__geo_interface__` of the series to get back GeoJSON-like shapes that rasterio expects as input.

Comment: Thanks thats all useful information that I will follow up.  However I am starting with vector shapefiles and not GeoJSON so was hoping for a method to rasterise a shapefile